# 'Polishing' a ClickOnce Deployment - How to?

Tags: clickonce

We are really close to releasing our first product as a ClickOnce deployment, but there are a couple of nagging issues that I just can't seem to resolve...

1. I know that in the ClickOnce deployment manifest, Windows XP and .NET 2.x is required for ClickOnce.  Our application has minimum requirements of Win XP w/ SP3, but I can't figure out how to force this to be checked prior to installation.  I considered using a custom bootstrapper, but don't really want to download (and install) another program simply to check for the right OS version.....
2. Is it possible to 'brand' the ClickOnce dialogs? The 'Verifying Application Requirements' and install dialogs?  How?
3. We need to support internationalized ClickOnce dialogs, but I can't seem to make the publish process from VS2010 use any language other than English.  I've changed the publish language (Properties -> Publish -> Options -> Publish Language, downloaded and installed the language packs from MS, etc.  Do I need a machine in the native culture to do this?  Or at least to test it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Our application has minimum
>   requirements of Win XP w/ SP3

I'm betting Windows 98 or Win2k won't even launch ClickOnce apps, so I wouldn't sweat it. That said, I don't think there's a way to specify minimum OS requirements in the ClickOnce manifest.

> Is it possible to 'brand' the
>   ClickOnce dialogs? The 'Verifying
>   Application Requirements' and install
>   dialogs? How?

No, not really. I believe you can get your application image/icon to show up in dialog. But the overall ClickOnce install experience is meant to be fast and consistent. Allowing apps to modify the install process breaks that.

Think of it like istalling an iPad or iPhone app. You don't sweat the install experience, you just make it fast and quick as possible. **Installation is a pain point for users**. Don't worry about plastering your logo over that thing. Just get it done quickly and as painless as possible.

Comment: thanks for the response.  My concern is whether Win XP w/o SP3 will support the .NET 4 Client framework - I know SP3 will, but don't have a way to test pre-SP3 installs.  And I didn't think I'd be able to re-brand the dialogs, but thought I'd ask in case I missed something.....